# BoxCox Transformation for time series with multiple instances

Tags: time-series, data-transformation

I have time series data with multiple instances. For example, instances like (`0.36,0.35,0.32,0.31,0.31,0.30,0.30,0.28,0.30`) occur 20 times ($20\times 9$ array). I am wondering how to do variance stabilization with boxcox transformation. Is connecting all instances to form one long series so boxcox is applied to this long series acceptable?

Comment: Connect them and look at the time series plot and then see if you need that Box-Cox transformation or not.